# onTaskRemoved not called on mi device

Tags: android

onTaskRemove() this method only called in the circumstances when your service start then after you press back button then after remove from recent task list that time this method called but if app foreground to background and then after killed then onTaskRemove() not called have any suggestion for this issue. working perfectly in the Samsung devices.

**code Example**

```
public class OnClearFromRecentService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Started");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e("ClearFromRecentService", "END............");
        //Code here
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: check very well also in Log.d and Log.e

Comment: hi. did you solve this? I am currently facing same issue ...

Answer (score 2):

consider using Activity's getLifecycle:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ...

    getLifecycle().addObserver(MyObserver(this))
}


class MyObserver(var context: Context) : LifecycleObserver {

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
fun disconnect() {
   //here you may add job you needed to fire in onTaskRemove()
}
```

}

Comment: That helped but with the help of AlarmManager, Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

onTaskRemoved() is called **only** when you clear process from recents. Same happenes to activity - if you just press home button activity goes to background but task (process) doesn't remove. If you need to stop process - just stop service or call .finishAndRemoveTask() for activity.

Comment: if your app in background then after you directly kill or remove from running tasks that time mi device not called onTaskRemoved() method but other devices work perfectly.

Comment: Have you checked process existence in Android monitor after killing it? Possibly your service runs with START_STYCKY flag and mi firmware just doesn't kill process in that case.

Comment: i will check service is exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

In phones like honour,mi onTaskRemoved() is not called until user set your app in whitelist.for mi phones we have intent:

```
 if (Build.BRAND.equals("xiaomi", ignoreCase = true)) {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.component =
            ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I check if user already allowed the app to be in white list ?